# TidyR solution to count str_detect's over multiple columns?

Tags: r, tidyr

I feel like I'm overthinking this and have been banging my head against the wall all day.  If this has been answered elsewhere I'm sorry, I've been trying to google it in various ways and found nothing.   I have a dataset kind of like:

```
PatientNum<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
Age<- c(10, 21, 51, 42, 35) 
ProcedureCode1 <- c(819.1, 820.1, 823.2, 946.5, 123.45) 
ProcedureCode2  <- c(126.78, 315.49, 687.32, 123.45, 823.2)
ProcedureCode3<-c(987.65,543.21,123.45,823.2,823.2) 



dataset <- data.frame(PatientNum, Age, ProcedureCode1,ProcedureCode2,ProcedureCode3)
```

I want to count how many times certain procedures happened for certain patients, regardless of column its found in, like so:

```
 CodesICareAbout<-c(123.45,987.65,823.2)
```

I know if I had exact numbers I could do  (this is what my expected output would be):

```
 dataset%>%mutate(NumberOfHits=((ProcedureCode1%in%CodesICareAbout+ProcedureCode2%in%CodesICareAbout+ProcedureCode3%in%CodesICareAbout)
```

But unfortunately my "CodesICareAbout" is actually not going to be an exact match.  I.e. I really have:

```
 CodesICareAbout<-c(123,987,823)
```

and the dataframe actually looks like:

```
PatientNum<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
Age<- c(10, 21, 51, 42, 35) 
ProcedureCode1 <- c("819.1 bla bla bla", "820.1 bla bla bla", "823.2bla bla bla", "946.5bla bla bla", "123.45bla bla bla") 
ProcedureCode2  <- c("126.78 bla bla bla", "315.49 bla bla bla", "687.32 bla bla bla", "123.45 bla bla bla", "823.2 bla bla bla")
ProcedureCode3<-c("987.65 bla bla bla","543.21 bla bla bla","123.45 bla bla bla","823.2 bla bla bla", "823.2 bla bla bla") 



dataset <- data.frame(PatientNum, Age, ProcedureCode1,ProcedureCode2,ProcedureCode3)
```

So I've been trying all sorts of combinations of str_detect and mutate and I got nothing.  I'd love anytime one of those codes I care about (lets say 123) pops up in one of those columns (even if its 123.45 bla bla bla) for it to count.  Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option. I collapse all the variables with procedure in the name, then count how many times one of your codes is in the really long string.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_cols(
  dataset,
  dataset %>%
  unite(col = "new",contains("Procedure"), sep = "") %>%
  select(new)
) %>%
  mutate(NumberOfHits = map_dbl(str_extract_all(new, str_c(CodesICareAbout, collapse = "|")), length)) %>%
  select(-new)
#>   PatientNum Age    ProcedureCode1     ProcedureCode2     ProcedureCode3
#> 1          1  10 819.1 bla bla bla 126.78 bla bla bla 987.65 bla bla bla
#> 2          2  21 820.1 bla bla bla 315.49 bla bla bla 543.21 bla bla bla
#> 3          3  51  823.2bla bla bla 687.32 bla bla bla 123.45 bla bla bla
#> 4          4  42  946.5bla bla bla 123.45 bla bla bla  823.2 bla bla bla
#> 5          5  35 123.45bla bla bla  823.2 bla bla bla  823.2 bla bla bla
#>   NumberOfHits
#> 1            1
#> 2            0
#> 3            2
#> 4            2
#> 5            3
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, I think I'd try to `gather()` the ProcedureCode variables, then checking the procedure code using `str_detect`, and finally grouping and summarizing.

Does this yield the result you're looking for?

```
PatientNum<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
Age<- c(10, 21, 51, 42, 35) 
ProcedureCode1 <- c(819.1, 820.1, 823.2, 946.5, 123.45) 
ProcedureCode2  <- c(126.78, 315.49, 687.32, 123.45, 823.2)
ProcedureCode3<-c(987.65,543.21,123.45,823.2,823.2) 


dataset <- data.frame(PatientNum, Age, ProcedureCode1,ProcedureCode2,ProcedureCode3)
CodesICareAbout<- "(123|987|823)" #using a regular expression here

dataset %>%
  gather(key = "proc_code_type", value = "code", ProcedureCode1:ProcedureCode3) %>%
  mutate(valid.code.check = str_detect(as.character(code), pattern = CodesICareAbout)) %>%
  group_by(PatientNum, Age) %>%
  summarise(code.care.about.count = sum(valid.code.check)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the the codes in the `ProcedureCode` variables are consistent with the first 3 digits as what you care about, using a bit of regex

```
CodesICareAbout <- c(123,987,823)
CodesICareAbout <- paste0("(", paste(CodesICareAbout, collapse = "|"), ")")

dataset %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("Code[0-9]$")), 
            list(yes = ~str_detect(., CodesICareAbout))) %>% 
  mutate(hits = rowSums(select(., matches("_yes$")))) %>% 
  select(-(matches("_yes")))
```